# Fetching data conditionally with useSWRImmutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, swr

i am trying to fetch data with useSWRImmutable,

The Problem here is that i am not getting any data inside UserRow component, tho I can print data outside UserRow component, the console.log() inside UserRow comonent is also not printing,

i don;t seem to figure out what i am missing here, please help me!

here's the code block,

```
    const {
        data: UserList,
        error,
        isLoading,
    } = useSWRImmutable([router?.isReady ? '/users' : null, params], ([url, filters]) => fetchUserList(url, filters));

    console.log(UserList,"hello");
```

fetchUserList method

```
const fetchUserList = async (url: any, filters: any) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(url, filters);
        return data.data;
    } catch (error) {}
};
```

Data Mapping

```
                               {UserList?.data?.length > 0 ? (
                                        UserList?.data?.map((data: any) => {
                                            <>
                                                {JSON.stringify(data)}
                                                <UserRow data={data} key={data.id} />
                                            </>;
                                        })
                                    ) : (
                                        <tr className="pointer-events-none">
                                            <td colSpan={6} className="p-8">
                                                <p className="mx-auto w-fit"> No data found.</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )}
```

here, i have made seperate component for table row as below

Table row:

```
interface IUserRow {
    data: any;
}

const UserRow = ({ data }: IUserRow) => {
    console.log(data, "inside row");

    return (
        <tr key={data.id}>
            <td>
                <div className="whitespace-nowrap">{data.id}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div className="whitespace-nowrap">{data.firstName}</div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div className="whitespace-nowrap">{data.email}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div className="whitespace-nowrap">{helper.formatDate(data.created_at)}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div
                    className={`status capitalize status-${helper.getAttorneyStatus(data?.status)}`}
                    // className="status status-approved"
                >
                    {helper.getAttorneyStatus(data?.status)}
                </div>
            </td>

            <td className="max-w-xs flex gap-2">
                <Link href={`/attorney/${data?.id}`}>
                    <Tippy content="View Details">
                        <span>
                            <IconEye className="action-icon text-secondary" />
                        </span>
                    </Tippy>
                </Link>
                <Tippy content="Edit Details">
                    <span>
                        <IconEdit className="action-icon text-secondary" />
                    </span>
                </Tippy>

                {data?.status === 4 && (
                    <Tippy content="Restore Expert">
                        <span>
                            <IconReload className="action-icon text-secondary" />
                        </span>
                    </Tippy>
                )}
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
};
```

i have tried to look into my code, but couldn't figure out what's off

Comment: i Found issue myself, i was missing return inside map

Answer (score 0):

I think the render heppens before UserList having a data, you can use an useEffect like this :

```
const [userListData, setUserListData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
setUserListData(UserList);
},[UserList]);
```

and in your **Data Mapping** you use **userListData** instead of **UserList**